# Fetching category name with a INNER JOIN

Tags: inner-join

I have a query that returns details of an item. It item belongs to a certain category; hence I have linked the ITEMS table to CATEGORIES table with a foreign key being saved to the ITEMS table.

Now, I want the details of any selected item to also display the category name instead of the foreign key. I have tried the `INNER JOIN` as follows, but surprisingly still the query displays a foreign key.

Here is my query:

```
/* Create the prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT categories.category AS category, 
                                     items.id, 
                                     items.name, 
                                     items.description 
                              FROM items
                              INNER JOIN categories
                                    ON categories.cat_id = items.cat_id
                              WHERE items.id='$id'")) { 

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Bind results to variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$category,$name,$description);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Out put for category name:

```
<?php  
echo $category;
?>
```

What could be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way out of my element, but nobody answered it yet so I figured I'd take a shot.

Is it because you are selecting 3 items in your query...  category, id, description

Then when you are binding variables you're binding 4...  $id,  $category, $name, $description

So perhaps what is happening is variable $id is actually the category, and $category is actually the id  (which is what you're seeing)

Answer (score 1):

Your binding order is wrong, it should be:

```
$stmt->bind_result($category, $id, $name, $description);
```

Your order in the SELECT clause matters, so `bind_result` can figure out wich column binds to wich variable.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be fetching 3 items (from your select) to 4 variables, I don't think this is good.